# arrayController "valueForUndefinedKey": why it gets istantiated immediately?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarraycontroller

My application has 2 windows, both of them are displaying NSScrollView objects managed by a controller. Basically the first has the data, the second has a proper aggregation of the data.
Both are relying of an implementation of NSArrayController class.

I designed both windows properly (I believe so at least) but I keep getting this error:

```
    [<MyDocument 0x1020257c0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key <MY_ARRAY>.
```

The only way I managed to solve this was to instantiate immediately (I mean when the first window gets prepared) the second array and populate it with some values this way:

```
NSMutableArray *newAggregates = [NSMutableArray array];

    [newAggregates addObject:
     [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [NSString stringWithString:@"category"], @"category",
      [NSString stringWithString:@"subcategory"], @"subcategory",
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], @"amount_1",
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], @"amount_2",
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], @"amount_3",
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], @"amount_4",
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], @"amount_5",
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], @"amount_6",
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], @"amount_7",
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], @"amount_8",
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], @"amount_9",
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], @"amount_10",
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], @"amount_11",
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], @"amount_12",
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], @"total",
      nil]];

    [self setAggregates:newAggregates];
```

This works, but it is not what I wanted, I want the second array to be executed only optionally, if and only if the user presses a certain button.

Is there a way to accomplish that, or any array controller present in the application has to be instantiated at the beginning? I am absolutely sure there must be a way to avoid that...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why your workaround works (Maybe your `setAggregates:` method prevents the call which eventually causes the error?). The error means that you have something bound to a property named `<MY_ARRAY>` on your document object. I would guess that it is probably the Content binding of one of your array controllers. You need to change it to the actual name of the property used in your class.

Comment: I don't get your point sorry, of course I have the NSView bound to my NSArrayController, but they are both belonging to a second window. My point is that I expected to have to initialize it when the second window got instantiated, i.e. opened...

Comment: The problem is that you bound the NSArrayController to the wrong thing, not that you need to initialize the array.

Comment: Well, I have bound the NSArrayController to the NSScrollView, frankly I am not sure my mistake is that, there are plenty of tutorials describing that as a way to achieve population of NSScrollView, there is definitely an error, but don't know which one. Anyway, thanks for your comment :)

Comment: @ughoavgfhw I know this answer is old, but I just wanted to let you know that it helped me diagnose the same error I was getting during a refactoring endeavor. I had an array controller bound to an NSManagedObjectContext object in my controller file and I moved the property to another class. It totally broke the binding and was spitting out this error which I couldn't figure out for the life of me. Even though the OP might not have understood what you were saying, others do! Thanks!!